# Where is the last red coin in "Many Fish in the Sea"?

Tags: yoshis-crafted-world

I've been through the level twice for the 20th red coin but can't seem to find it. Is it hiding behind some secret tab somewhere? Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Many Fish]

After the egg flower, there is a present hidden behind a row of coins accessible after pounding a pillar. Hit it with an egg for the last coin.